# function to split a filepath into path and file

Tags: c, string

Lets say I have a function:

```
void split_path_file(char** p, char** f, char *pf)
{
    //malloc and set *p to file path, malloc and set *f to file name
    //pf is the pointer to the full file and path "C:\sponge\bob\square.pants"
    // edit: leave pf in its origional state
}
```

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void split_path_file(char** p, char** f, char *pf) {
    char *slash = pf, *next;
    while ((next = strpbrk(slash + 1, "\\/"))) slash = next;
    if (pf != slash) slash++;
    *p = strndup(pf, slash - pf);
    *f = strdup(slash);
}
```

(If `pf == slash`, then there is no directory component.)

Comment: I don't like using `strdup()` because it's non-standard, but I _really_ don't like using `strndup()` because my compiler doesn't have it. :P

Comment: PS: I was using an (old) compiler that does not have **strndup()**. 
Here is the code to cut/paste (add the #include <stddef.h> too)

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834385/split-path-into-two-segments

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but the best solution I have found and have been using for years is the two functions `dirname` and `basename`

```
path         dirname    basename
"/usr/lib"    "/usr"    "lib"
"/usr/"       "/"       "usr"
"usr"         "."       "usr"
"/"           "/"       "/"
```

They are great for separating parts of a path/filename. Together with realpath() they are IMHO unbeatable in simplicity and power.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Comment: One limitation to realpath() seems to be that it requires you to be executing it on the machine where the filesystem is located and for you to have access to all the directories along the path.  For some situations, this would not work well or there would be a performance hit since you are needing to access the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Go backwards through the string until you reach the first '\\' then set *f to everything after it and *p to everything before and the '\\'.

Comment: You need to make at least one forward pass in order to find the terminating `'\0'` of a C string -- there's no reason not to scan for slashes while on the way forwards instead of starting a second pass in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way seems to be to start from the end and work towards the beginning, looking for the first delimiter character. You then have two cases: either you found one or you didn't. Something like this should do it for you:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_path_file(char **p, char **f, char *pf) {
  char *newcopy = malloc(strlen(pf) + 1);
  strcpy(newcopy, pf);

  for (z=newcopy+strlen(newcopy); z>newcopy; z--) {
    if (*z == '/' || *z == '\\')
      break;
  }

  if (z > newcopy) {
    *p = newcopy;
    *z = '\0';
    *f = z+1;
  } else {
    *f = newcopy;
    *p = NULL;
  }
}
```

Update: @ephemient's comment below points out the above approach doesn't leave `*p` and `*f` suitable for calling `free()`. If this is important, something a little more complicated like this will be needed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_path_file(char **p, char **f, char *pf) {

  /* Find last delimiter. */
  char *z;
  for (z=pf+strlen(pf); z>=pf; z--) {
    if (*z == '/' || *z == '\\')
      break;
  }

  if (z >= pf) {
    /* There is a delimiter: construct separate
       path and filename fragments. */
    printf("--> %i\n", z-pf);
    *p = malloc(z-pf+1);
    strncpy(*p, pf, z-pf);
    (*p)[z-pf] = '\0';
    *f = malloc(strlen(z));
    strcpy(*f, z+1);
  } else {
    /* There is no delimiter: the entire
       string must be a filename. */
    *p = NULL;
    *f = malloc(strlen(pf)+1);
    strcpy(*f, pf);
  }
}
```

Comment: This probably violates OP's request that `*p` and `*f` be `malloc`ed: horrible failure ensues if the caller tries to `free(*f)` which is an offset into another `malloc`ed area.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, of course this assumes that pf is malloced.

```
void split_path_file(char** p, char **f, char *pf)
{
    char *posp = strrchr(pf, '\\');
    *posp = '\0';
    *p = strdup(pf);
    *f = strdup(posp+1);
    *posp = '\\';
}
```

Not sure if this is a better approach than above answers.

Comment: This violates OP's request that `pf` not be modified, and segfaults if there is a filename without directory.  Also, note that forward slash is still a valid path separation character on Windows.

Comment: Nevermind on the first point: you restore the backslash.  However, the other two may still be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

```
int
stripfilenameandpath (char *path, char *onlypath, char *onlyfilename)
{
/*
documentacao

path = path com path e arquivo
onlypath = somente o path
onlyfilename = somente o arquivo sem o path

*/
    int ret;
    int i;
    int p;
    char temp[255];

    char *fixo;
#ifdef WIN32
    const int separator = '\\';
#else
    const int separator = '/';
#endif

    fixo = path;

    if (path == NULL)
      {

          if (onlypath != NULL)
            {
                memset (onlypath, 0, 1);
            }

          if (onlyfilename != NULL)
            {
                memset (onlyfilename, 0, 1);
            }

          return 1;
      }

    ret = strlen (path);

    if (!ret)
      {

          if (onlypath != NULL)
            {
                memset (onlypath, 0, 1);
            }

          if (onlyfilename != NULL)
            {
                memset (onlyfilename, 0, 1);
            }

          return 0;
      }

    for (i = 0; i  -1; i--)
      {

          if (temp[i] == separator)
            {
                temp[i + 1] = 0;
                break;
            }
          p++;
      }

    p = ret - p;

    fixo += p + 1;

    if (onlypath != NULL)
      {
          strcpy (onlypath, temp);
      }

    if (onlyfilename != NULL)
      {
          strcpy (onlyfilename, fixo);
      }

    return 0;
}
```