# Split path into two segments

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function to split a filepath into path and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575278/function-to-split-a-filepath-into-path-and-file)

I want to split a pathname like "a/b/c/directory/filename" into "a/b/c/directory" and "filename". What's a good way to do that in C?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char path[] ="/aaa/bbb/ccc/file";
  char *part1 = (char *)malloc (strlen(path));
  strcpy (part1, path);
  char *pos = strrchr (part1, '/');
  *pos = '\0';
  char *part2 = strdup (pos + 1);
  printf ("%s \n%s", part1, part2 );

}
```