# Cutting a string in C with specified character

Tags: c

For example, I have a string"`/home/george/file.c`", I want to cut the string to be "`file.c`", so just get rid of all string before the last '`/`' character.

Comment: [Split the string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9210528/102937) on `/`, and take the last element in the split.

Comment: You want to look up the `basename()` function.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575278/function-to-split-a-filepath-into-path-and-file)?

Answer (score 5):

There's a function called `basename` that'll do just that.  See `man 3 basename` on how to use it.

Comment: Note that `basename` is not part of the c standard library, though it is very widely available. The man page on my mac claims *"The basename() function conforms to X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4, Version 2 (``XPG4.2'')."*

Answer (score 1):

Here, it is possible to use `strrchr` from `<string.h>` header. Look at [its documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html).

```
#include <string.h>

char *end = strrchr(string, '/') + 1;
char result[SIZE];

if (end != NULL)
    strcpy(result, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the string library, you can just get the length of the string, then start walking backwards until you hit your first '/' character.  Then, take that index and use substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *filename = strrchr(path, '/'); // this points `filename` at the final '/'
if (filename)                        // if that succeeded
   ++filename;                       //     we want the next character
else                                 // otherwise
     filename = path;                //     what's in path is all the file name.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `basename()` defined in the header file `<libgen.h>`
. The prototype of `basename()` is `char *basename(const char *fname);`. It returns a pointer into the original file name where the basename starts.

In your case the code should be as follows,

```
char ch="/home/george/file.c"
char *ptr;
ptr=basename(ch);
printf("The file name is %s",ptr);
```